# sql count and select couple rows

Tags: sql, count

I want to write a query that will return the next result:

```
[
   [0] => [
        'login' => 'user',
        'count' => '2'
   ],
   [1] => [
       'login' => 'test',
       'count' => '2'
   ]
]
```

Explanation:
`login` column is a simple column with data and count is a COUNT of all results. 
If I write

```
SELECT login, COUNT(*) FROM `users` WHERE 1 GROUP BY `users`.`id`
```

I'll get next data:

```
[
   [0] => [
        'login' => 'user',
        'count' => '1'
   ],
   [1] => [
       'login' => 'test',
       'count' => '1'
   ]
]
```

As you see COUNT isn't correct(I need 2).
If I don't use GROUP statement I will get next data:

```
[
   [0] => [
        'login' => 'user',
        'count' => '2'
   ],
]
```

COUNT is correct but not all data was fetched.
Is it possible to fetch all this stuff for one query without subquery ?

Thank you.

Comment: What is `2` supposed to represent? If `users.id` is a PK, `count` will be 1.

Comment: count of selected items. If query have to return 10 records then count also must be equal to 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 select login as ID,(select COUNT(*) from users)  as USERCOUNT  from users;
```

By using a nested select statement as a column and defining it with a non-function name, it will return the result of the select statement with the table.

Comment: So, basically you want to say that only nested query can help?

Comment: No,  depending on the programming language you are using, a variety of different solutions can exist.  Its possible to perform the query regularly without using the COUNT() function at all, then using whatever language is calling the SQL lookup to count the number of records returned.  That actually may be the easiest way